# Selenium and interacting with searchbar

Tags: python, selenium

Hi I'm new to selenium but trying to automate searching on angel.co without success! The search box element changes when clicked on and I'm having difficuly with selenium being able to pick up the elements to do things on. Essentially I want to input growth hacker into the box and do a search. You have to first click on the box, type in the search term and then press enter.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver.get("https://angel.co/jobs")

time.sleep(5)

 WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located
 ((By.XPATH,"//[@id='main']/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/
 button/div")))

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/button/div')

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = 'Growth Hacker';",element)

time.sleep(5)

element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN')
```

I get as far as being able to input the Growth Hacker into the box, but can't make it become a tag as all search terms do in this search box.

Any help would be really appreciated.

UPDATE

I've managed to insert text into the box but for some reason I can't seem to get it to turn into the tag with the correct text on the search box.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver.get("https://angel.co/jobs")

WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//span[@class="label_82eab"]')))

element4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="label_82eab"]')
time.sleep(5)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText='Edinburgh';",element4)
time.sleep(5)
WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//span[@class="label_82eab"]')))

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="label_82eab"]').click()
```

[Before Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pT6zm.png)

[After click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnX1c.png)

[Text to Change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu7l6.png)

Answer (score 0):

> So i tried my own way and was able to search inputted result, you can try the code and see if its what you want, because your question wanst clear enough. From my understanding your finding difficulties in searching the text field which works fine in my code. Try it out and let me know if i can help !

You can always write the code without the classes if your not familiar with selenium and classes!

```
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
    import unittest, time, re


class Angel(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("change to ur chrome driver")
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)


def test_angel(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("https://angel.co/")
    driver.find_element_by_id("search").click()
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_id("search").clear()
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_id("search").send_keys("Growth Hacker")
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_id("search").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(3)



def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Hi thanks so much for the help! I was actually wanting to search from within https://angel.co/jobs. There's a search box there with the element <button class="inactive_10b02 hasRoles_43a3f">. On clicking this changes to <div class="css-1pcexqc-container component_ec1a8>. I can't for the life of me track why that changes with the <script>, basically want to select the element to input my own search terms. Any ideas ?

I wish actually I could track how javascript changes the html.

Comment: I've updated the question as I've managed to enter text into the field but still not able to make it stick. Provided pics for the html to make it clearer! I appreciate the tiem you've taken.

Comment: Any ideas ? Ive been thining about xpath selectors that work with dynamic html as a way to get around this. I'll report back if I have anything but would be grateful for input.